# Is the Content-Length header the size in bytes of the compressed or uncompressed bytes?

Tags: node.js, http, webserver

I'm implementing static file serving in node.js. Let's say I am sending a  file called `party-time.txt` which is:

`100 bytes uncompressed`

`70 bytes gzipped`

If I send the file gzipped, should the `Content-Length` header be `100` or `70`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please have a look at the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-119). It clearly states:

> Applications SHOULD use this field to indicate the transfer-length of
> the message-body, unless this is prohibited by the rules in section
> 4.4.

Digging deeper:

> The message-body (if any) of an HTTP message is used to carry the
> entity-body associated with the request or response. The message-body
> differs from the entity-body only when a transfer-coding has been
> applied, as indicated by the Transfer-Encoding header field (...)

So, the `Content-length` is the size of compressed body.